# Remove diacritics from string for search function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am developing a simple web page with Django and I need to implement search function. I am currently using something like this:

```
search_box = request.GET['search_box']
X = Foo.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=search_box) | Q(info__contains=search_box)).values()
```

It checks my database if specified columns contains searched string, but what if I search for "kočík" but my database contains "kocik". How I can remove diacritis from string in Python 3, or what is the best way to implement this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `unicodedata` package for that.

```
import unicodedata
def shave_marks(txt):
    """This method removes all diacritic marks from the given string"""
    norm_txt = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', txt)
    shaved = ''.join(c for c in norm_txt if not unicodedata.combining(c))
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', shaved)
```

**Some details about this algorithm:**

The main problem with diacritics is that in UTF-8 some are combining characters that modify the preceding character, and yet others are included with the character. For example, `'café'` and `'cafe/u0301'` look the same.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html:

> Even if two unicode strings are normalized and look the same to a human reader, if one has combining characters and the other doesn’t, they may not compare equal.

This algorithm first decomposes a string (using 'NFD' method) so that all diacritics become combining characters, then it filters out all combining characters, and lastly composes the string (using 'NFC' method).

Comment: Just briliant. Thanks!